# How to resolve the error ImportError: cannot import name 'GenerationConfig' from 'transformers'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, torch

I am using Paperspace for programming. I want to import `AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead, PPOConfig, PPOTrainer`  from **trl** but I  I encountered an error.  I installed the required libraries such as `torch==1.9.0 or 2.0.1`,
`transformers==4.18.0`, and `trl`. After importing the libraries as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import torch
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer

from trl import AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead, PPOConfig, PPOTrainer
```

I got the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'GenerationConfig' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/__init__.py)`

Please be aware that the code functions correctly when using `Google Colab`. However, when running it on `Paperspace`, I encountered an error. It seems that the version of `PyTorch` on Paperspace is `1.12.1`, which is not suitable for my requirements. I attempted to create a virtual environment to install a different version of PyTorch, but unfortunately, the version remains `1.12.1`. Although I managed to update PyTorch to higher versions like `2.0.1`, I encountered a conflicting dependency error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.13.1+cu116 requires torch==1.12.1, but you have torch 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.12.1+cu116 requires torch==1.12.1, but you have torch 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

Even with the latest version of PyTorch, the error persists, and I am still unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `torchvision` and `torchaudio` are not compatible with your current `torch` version. Try to install pytorch's stable version (2.0.1) using this command:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

or generate the desired combination from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/.

See also [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77196652/2314737).